# Retrofit path encode except character?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I use retrofit and my interface below

```
 @GET("{link}")
 fun search(@Path(value = "link", encoded = true) link: String?): Call<Any>
```

Do I need to use encoded for all link except character '?'.

***Example:***

**Link ->** /api/search?&query=تست

**Encoded link by retrofit ->** api/search%3F&query=%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AA

**I need this link->** api/search?&query=%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AA

I need don't convert character **'?'** to **%3F**.
do is anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution, must use Interceptor for the request.

```
class RemoveCharacterInterceptor : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()
        val path = request.url().toString()

        val string = path.replace("%3F", "?") // replace

        val newRequest = request.newBuilder()
                .url(string)
                .build()

        return chain.proceed(newRequest)
    }

}
```

and add to httpClient

```
val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
httpClient.addInterceptor(RemoveCharacterInterceptor())
```

Comment: It will work until you'll try to send '?' in some query parameter.
Seems buggy to me.

Comment: this worked for me. tnk u :)

Answer (score 5):

@Url should be used for this instead of @Path

```
@GET
Call<ResponseClass> list(@Url String url);
```

It works fine with full URL and a path that is used then with base URL.

```
Retrofit retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()  
  .baseUrl("https://website.com/");
  .build();

MyService service = retrofit.create(MyService.class);  
service.exampleCall("https://another-website.com/example");
service.anotherExampleCall("/only/path/part");
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Path ,you can use `@Query`  in your method,it won't convert `?` to `%3F` .
You can change your method to

```
@GET("api/serach")
fun search(@Query("query") value: String?): Call<Any>
```

For example,your value is "aolphn",this code will access

```
http(s)://xxx/api/search?query=aolphn
```

`?` will appended automatically.

Comment: i need add path no query

Comment: maybe you can just add path and do not add query=? in your path,so your code could be  `fun search(@Path(value = "link", encoded = true),@Query("query") str: String?): Call<Any>` you can add link as your path.

Comment: If you need to add `@Path` then you will be using a `PathParam` so you don't need the "?" character. I think what you are looking for is a `QueryParam` as @Aolphn stated.